# Nokia In App Billing ( Error checking for billing v3 support )

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, nokiax

I am trying to integrate Nokia in App purchase in one of my application.I am able to run it on Nokia X simulator.But when I try to execute same code on Nokia X device I am facing following issue.

I tried doing clear data for Nokia Store app but it didn't worked.

[image]

Can somebody please guide me If I am missing something.

Thanks :-)

Comment: is the billing supported call returning true? and which code part would it be that causes thus error.

Comment: @Dr.Jukka Thanks a ton sir! It resolved my issue.I have raised one more question regarding Nokia In-App Billing.It would be great If you can have look at the question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response 9 is:
RESULT_NO_SIM = 9 - Billing is not available because there is no SIM card inserted

If you have SIM insterted and you still get that answer, it might mean that you operator is not supporting Nokia In-App Payments

Br,
Janne Koskinen

Comment: I was just wondering how In app purchase is linked to presense of Sim card.Since in Android user is going to enter his credit card details to buy item.

Comment: with Nokia X, there is only Operator billing available, thus the SIM is required